# Reaction of alkyl halides with strong unhindered bases

Tags: organic-chemistry, reaction-mechanism

Please look at the image on this website: http://www.physicsforums.com/showthread.php?t=765853

For (b) and (c), what the solution manual says makes no sense to me.
You're reacting a primary alkyl halide with an unhindered base $\ce{EtONa}$. They say that the only product is the alkene. Why do they not consider the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction that WILL take place in larger quantity?
I'm uploading the question too on the other website

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with you, I'd expect some $\mathrm{S_N2}$ product too. I'm not sure about the relative quantities of the $\mathrm{E2}$ and $\mathrm{S_N2}$ products though.

I wouldn't flat out say that you'd expect more $\mathrm{S_N2}$ product than $\mathrm{E2}$ product, because although the substrate is unhindered, the solvent is ethanol, which is protic. The solvent interacts with the nucleophile through hydrogen bonding.

This hinders the nucleophile. This slows down the rate of the $\mathrm{S_N2}$ reaction because now the nucleophile is dragging along lots of solvent molecules, and it also increases the bulk of the nucleophile.

Comment: How does the solvent being protic hinder the nucleophile?

Comment: The solvent can hydrogen bond with the nucleophile.

Comment: Ok. Now, does that mean that E2 is favored in a strict sense?

Comment: Er that's a hard call to make without actually doing the experiment.

Comment: Ok. I just consulted my textbook. It seems as though Sn1 and Sn2 are really impacted by solvent. E2 and E1 are indirectly concerned and as you say need the experiment. Great help! I'll post another question that was racking my brains.

Comment: I'm not sure what the effect of protic vs aprotic solvent would be on the product distribution here. However, it is definitely not true there is no solvent effect on basicity. Just as hydrogen bonding decreases nucleophilicity, it decreases basicity.

Comment: Wouldn't the protic solvent hinder the nucleophile? Just as F- is a bad nucleophile in water, it is a good nucleophile in a non-protic solvent.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Similarly though, hydroxide is a strong base in water, but it's stronger in an aprotic solvent or in the gas phase.